# How do I "unconvert" an app from South (Django)?

Tags: django, django-south

I changed a lot in my `models.py`, including deleting a lot of fields, and renaming a couple of classes. `schemamigration --auto` worked fine, but trying `migrate` threw a bunch of errors.

All my code is currently in development so I don't mind too much losing the data. So I want South to "unconvert" or "unmanage" an app so I can rebuild all the tables with `syncdb` again.

Or I could delete all migration list and do `schemamigration --initial` again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just delete the migrations and run `schemamigration --initial` again. You should do that anyways as normal course before moving to production. If you've already gone to production at least once, don't delete all the migrations -- just the ones you've created in the current development cycle and then run `schemamigration --auto` to get just one migration instead of the potential multiple ones.

FWIW, to "unconvert" an app using South, you merely delete the "migrations" directory, but in this scenario, there's no need.

**UPDATE**

It was pointed out that if you have already migrated your app, and you delete all the migrations and generate a single new one, South will complain about migrations still in the database. The actual process you should follow is:

1. Rollback to the just before the newest migration you created in the current development cycle. For instance, if you were already at 0005 and you created three new migrations for the development work you were doing (now at 0008), you would rollback to 0005. If all of the migrations are new, you rollback to `zero`:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate yourapp zero
   ```
2. Delete all of the migrations you're going to merge. In the above example, that would be 0006, 0007, and 0008, or for a new app, everything in the migrations directory but `__init__.py`.
3. Generate a new migration to cover the ones you just deleted. If it's a new app, use `--initial`, or if it was a pre-existing app, use `--auto`.

   ```
   python manage.py schemamigration --initial yourapp
   ```
4. Migrate

   ```
   python manage.py migrate yourapp
   ```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation. What's the code for deleting a migration?

Comment: Just physically delete the file. There's no command -- just the normal way you delete anything.

Comment: Ah ok, I was trying to find a delete command from the South documentation lol. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually if you delete the files, South will warn that although the files are gone, the migration information still exist in the database. Then there is this option to get rid of "ghost" files or something. I forgot the command, but it removes the information from the database as well.

Comment: The option is `--ignore-ghost-migrations` and was added in South 0.7.1

Comment: Sorry, yes, I assumed you were starting with a blank DB since you were having problems migrating. In development, it's best to rollback first, delete the migrations, generate the new single migration and then migrate. I'll update my answer.