# Removing an app from South

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I am new to South and the migrations and I accidentally converted django.contrib.admin and django.contrib.auth to South. Is there a way for me to remove them from South so I can sync them normally with syncdb?

I checked and there is nothing in the south migration history.

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "unconvert" an app from South (Django)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670762/how-do-i-unconvert-an-app-from-south-django)

Answer (score 0):

1: Delete the migrations directory

2: From your database schema, from the south_migrationhistory table, delete the entry where app_name is equal to 'admin' and 'auth' (i'm basically talking about an operation on your database).

The second step is more for cleaning up, than for necessity, but anyway, that's all south does: create a 'migrations' directory, and write entries in the table 'south_migrationhistory' recording all the migrations that were applied (migrations = files inside the 'migrations' folder)